# NPOI Date Format Cell

Tags: c#, date, format, cell, npoi

I'm using NPOI to create fixed worksheet template in Sheet1, and need data from Sheet2 that's in date format.I generate DataTable from database to set data in Sheet2. 
It's my code :

```
private DataTable getWeek()
{    
  strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
  conn = new OdbcConnection(strConn);
  conn.Open();
  sql = "SELECT week, sunday, saturday FROM tb_weekreferences";     
  da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);
  dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(dt);
  conn.Close();        

  return dt;

}
```

and then export DataTable to Excel :

```
private int ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable sourceTable, ISheet sheet)
    {
        IRow headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
        ICell headerCell;
        ICell cell = null;
        Dictionary<String, ICellStyle> styles = CreateExcelStyles(hssfwb);

        //handling value
        int rowIdx = 1;
        foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows)
        {
            IRow dataRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowIdx);            
            foreach (DataColumn column in sourceTable.Columns)
            {
                cell = dataRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal);                
                cell.SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
                cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("");
                cell.CellStyle = styles["cell"]; 
            }            
            rowIdx++;
        }

        //handling header
        foreach (DataColumn column in sourceTable.Columns)
        {
            headerCell = headerRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal);
            headerCell.SetCellValue(column.ColumnName);
            headerCell.CellStyle = styles["header"];
            sheet.AutoSizeColumn(column.Ordinal);
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(column.Ordinal, (sheet.GetColumnWidth(column.Ordinal) + (5 * 256))); // set width = autofit() + (5 * 256)
        }
        return rowIdx;
    }
```

In Sheet1 i use vlookup formula to get 'sunday' and 'saturday' from Sheet2. But it doesn't work, because value of week, sunday, and saturday in Sheet2 seems like string (left alignment cell). How to set cell format in date when generate data to excel ?
Please give me solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First problem is this line

```
cell.SetCellValue(row[column].ToString());
```

You are converting value to string, but you probably convert it to DateTime format, so NPOI knows this is datetime.

or try if this works:

```
cell.SetCellValue(DateTime.Now);
```

Second, try first set the style for your cell and then change it DataFormat attribute, but with custom format like this:

```
IDataFormat dataFormatCustom = workbook.CreateDataFormat();
cell.CellStyle = styles["cell"]; 
cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
```

which will format your DateTime value to human readable format.

Comment: in your first code will be get date in now, but i need get date from other sheet.

Comment: And i have tried your second code, it doesn't work, format cell still like in sheet2  (as string) by vlookup formula.

Comment: So seems like you have problem in Sheet2. Are you able to convert that date to DataTime format when you populate Sheet2 from database (before doing lookup)? What format do you have in database?
Maybe in your DataTable which you read ith getWeek() method you could create some temporary columns with dates in DateTime format instead of string and use those for lookup?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008, field 'sunday' and 'saturday' is date.
in sql query i convert with :
convert(varchar(9), sunday, 6) as Sunday -> 31 Dec 12.
when export from datatable to excel, i check type of column :
if(type == "System.DateTime"){
cell.CellValue(Convert.ToDateTime(row[column]));
}
if type is Int or String it's work, but in date i get this error :
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: you have better idea ?

Comment: why do you convert your date (sunday, saturday column) to string at all? Can't you return from sql to your datatable just plain date (sunday field) in DateTime format? 

I think this is not needed 'convert(varchar(9), sunday, 6) as Sunday'

I think instead this you should apply formating on excel side in NPOI if you need this, as I mentioned in my orginal reply.

Comment: okay, i know the problem now.
although the result in excel is number, it can be changed to date format by your second code.
Thank's for your help, Juri.